# How to send formData from Angular 2 to nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, angular

I'm using this code:

```
var creds = "username=" + 'user' + "&password=" + 'password';
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
http.post('http://localhost:3000/', creds, {
  headers : headers
})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => this.logData(data),
        err => this.logError(err),
    () => console.log('Quote Complete')
);
```

NodeJs got json { username: 'user', password: 'password' }   on this.request.body . But I need json like {fields: { username: 'user', password: 'password' } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use url encoded form only, you can't. In fact, your Node application will convert / deserialize the string content (`username=user&password=somepwd`) into a simple (and flat) JavaScripty object.

To achieve what you want (a specific format) for the data you receive in the Node application, you need to switch to a `application/json` content type for your request payload, as described below:

```
var creds = {
  fields: {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'password'
  }
}

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
http.post('http://localhost:3000/', JSON.stringify(creds), {
  headers : headers
})
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => this.logData(data),
    err => this.logError(err),
    () => console.log('Quote Complete')
  );
```

Don't forget to register the correct deserializer within your Node application. For example with Express:

```
var express = require('express');
var application = express();

application.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

Make the object of the specified format, use json.stringify to make a string out of it and send it to node.js server.